# Set VisualTreeItem.Select handler in C# code behinde

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, handler

Now I set hanler in XAML

```
<TreeView x:Name="ArticlesTreeView" TreeViewItem.Selected="ArticlesTreeView_OnItemSelected">
```

But I need do this in my `.cs` file. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to get SelectedItem in codebehind?

Comment: @Krishna Yes, I use it to get selected `TreeViewItem`. In my case it is the only possible option.

Comment: Can you not use SelectedItemChanged event for the treeview and access the ItemSelected in that event in code behind?

Comment: @Krishna In my case it only possible option, because `ItemSelected` has my oun class, and I can't get `TreeViewItem` object for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ArticlesTreeView.AddHandler(TreeViewItem.SelectedEvent, 
                        new RoutedEventHandler(ArticlesTreeView_OnItemSelected));
```

`TreeViewItem.SelectedEvent` is called ***attached event***.

More about [UIElement.AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598898(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, when I little correct this string it works `ArticlesTreeView.AddHandler(TreeViewItem.SelectedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ArticlesTreeView_OnItemSelected));`

Comment: @beta-tank yes, missed about that, the argument type is `Delegate` not a direct eventhandler type. More exactly it should be a `RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler`.